# SQL string loop for generated fields on ASP.Net webform

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sql, asp.net

I have the following ASP.Net webform that has a button which can be clicked by the user to generate a bunch of fields (using Javascript) on the form. I also have a bunch of static fields on the form and the values entered on the static fields are transferred to a SQL table. I am having great troubles transferring values that are being entered on the generated fields with a button click. As of now, I'm naming the generated textboxes as txtDimension 2 & so on. I need help to create a SQL string loop that would help me transfer values from both the generated and static fields on the webform.

This is my ASP.Net button code:

```
<script src="check.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="divDimensions" class="auto-style9">
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Add More Fields" OnClientClick="return addInput('divDimensions');" CssClass="auto-style10" Height="68px" Width="236px" />
    </div>
       <p class="auto-style9">
           &nbsp;</p>
    <p class="auto-style9">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" Width="191px" Height="82px" />
    </p>
```

Javascript code for the ASP.Net button that the user clicks to generate additional fields on the webform:

```
 var counter = 1;

 var limit = 1000;

 function addInput(divName) {


if (counter == limit) {

    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");

}

else {

    var table = document.getElementById("tableChecksheet");
    var row = table.insertRow();
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.className = "auto-style3"
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "<h2>Dimension Type " + (counter + 1); 
    cell2.innerHTML = "<br><input id='txtdimensiontype " + (counter + 1) + "' type='text' name='myInputs[]' style='width: 500px;'>";

    var row = table.insertRow();
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.className = "auto-style3"
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "<h2>Dimension " + (counter + 1);
    cell2.innerHTML = "<br><input id='txtdimension " + (counter + 1) + "' type='text' name='myInputs[]' style='width: 500px;'>";
counter++;
}


 }
```

C# code behind webform that transfers values entered in the static fields from the webform as of now, I want a SQL string loop for the generated fields:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
  using System.Data.SqlClient;
  using System.Configuration;

  namespace WebApplication3
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        var connectionString = @strConn;
        var query = @"INSERT INTO Checksheets (DimensionType, Dimension) VALUES (@sixthword,@seventhword);";
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
              command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sixthword", txtdimensiontype.Text));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@seventhword", txtdimension.Text));


                var Reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            }
        }
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: I did something similar actually with dynamic fields but I used a SQL Stored Procedure. 
 This would be much easier to use C# to populate a c# object and pass that object as a TableType to a SQL Stored Procedure.
in SP call:  @NameValuePairAnswers as dbo.NameValuePairTable READONLY

Comment: CREATE TYPE [dbo].[NameValuePairTable] AS TABLE(
 [Name] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
 [Value] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL
)
GO

Comment: Thanks Brad for your reply. This is my first time coding something like this and that's why I don't really understand the SQL Stored Procedure that you're talking about. Can you please provide me with a sample code that applies to my code above so that I can use that? Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

```
-- for table type to pass to SP
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[NameValuePairTable] AS TABLE( DimensionType [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL, Dimension [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL ) GO


-- call SP from C# code and pass it the table type object
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveResultsFromForm]    
    @NameValuePairAnswers as dbo.NameValuePairTable READONLY
AS
BEGIN

        -- this will insert ALL answers from the web form you passed from the c# object
        INSERT INTO Checksheets (DimensionType, Dimension) 
        Select DimensionType, Dimension
        FROM @NameValuePairAnswers 

END
```

c#

```
      // now build out the namevalue pair paramater to pass to SP call
        SqlParameter TableData = new SqlParameter();
        TableData.ParameterName = "@NameValuePairAnswers";
        TableData.TypeName = "dbo.NameValuePairTable";
        TableData.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
        // this will be the C# object you populated from your form as a C# datatype DataTable
        TableData.Value = FormResultsDataTable;
```

---

updated to add more c# code

```
string SQL = "EXEC dbo.SaveResultsFromForm @NameValuePairAnswers = @NameValuePairAnswers";
                SqlCommand InsertDataCommand = new SqlCommand(sSQL);


                // now build out the namevalue pair paramater
                SqlParameter TableData = new SqlParameter();
                TableData.ParameterName = "@NameValuePairAnswers";
                TableData.TypeName = "dbo.NameValuePairTable";
                TableData.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                TableData.Value = FormResultsDataTable;

                // now add the tabledata to the list
                InsertDataCommand.Parameters.Add(TableData);

                // to execute the command to SQL
                InsertDataCommand.Execute()
```

Comment: Do I put the first part of the code (call SP code from C#) into C# code? I copied everything into the C# code but it's giving me errors for every line.

Comment: No the top code you have to do in SQL to generate the SQL objects that you are going to call in C# and the c# code is just partial code to call populate the table variable you need to call the SQL SP

Comment: I added more c# code to call.  You will still have get the data from your form submission into a c# datatable